# How to recording the user's device in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

how to add data device (tablet, mobile, desktop) if users access to one of the devices when logged on, then the data was recorded.

i use packages jenssegers/agent

table **device** having column: device_name, date

i try, but can't record in table

this my code in LoginController.php

```
   public function check(){
      $agent = new Agent();
      $dt = Carbon::now();

      if ( $agent->isDesktop() == true )
      {
        DB::table('device')->insert([
           ['device_name' => 'desktop', 'tgl' => $dt->toDateString()],
       ]);
      }

      elseif ($agent->isTablet() == true) {
        DB::table('device')->insert([
           ['device_name' =>'tablet', 'tgl' => $dt->toDateString()],
       ]);
      }

      elseif ($agent->isMobile() == true) {
        DB::table('device')->insert([
           ['device_name' => 'mobile', 'tgl' => $dt->toDateString()],
       ]);
     }

    }
```

please help me, thank you very much...

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @eddy, not got an error, but cant record to table

Comment: Is your table called `device` or `devices`? Do you have timestamps `created_at` and `updated_at` ?

Comment: my table name is "device", no timestamp but i using date

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://codezen.io/how-to-manage-logged-in-devices-in-laravel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code, it seems that your code doesn't go into any of the `if-else` statement?

```
public function check(){
  $agent = new Agent();
    $dt = Carbon::now();

    $device_name = '';
    if ($agent->isDesktop()) {
        $device_name = 'desktop';
    } elseif ($agent->isTablet()) {
        $device_name = 'tablet';
    } elseif ($agent->isMobile()) {
        $device_name = 'mobile';
    }

    DB::table('device')->insert([
        ['device_name' => $device_name, 'tgl' => $dt->toDateString()],
    ]);

}
```

Comment: value $agent->isDesktop() is true, if a user accesses using Desktop. etc...

Comment: can't insert in table... no record

Comment: device_name column is empty.... no recorded... only id and date recorded

Comment: The `insert()` works, the package you use couldn't detect if it was a desktop, tablet or mobile then.

Comment: i try write in index home, value $agent->isDesktop() is TRUE... 

this is i try using desktop

Comment: SOLVED... I false in typing enum value in table....

THank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

this my full code LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\Management\Radcheck;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Debugbar;
use Jenssegers\Agent\Agent;
use Date;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;





    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
   {

       if ( ! Radcheck::where('username', $request->username)->first() ) {
           return redirect()->back()
               ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
               ->withErrors([
                   $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.username'),

               ]);
       }

       if ( ! Radcheck::where('username', $request->username)->where('password', bcrypt($request->password))->first() ) {
           return redirect()->back()
               ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
               ->withErrors([
                   'password' => Lang::get('auth.password'),
                   /*Debugbar::error('Put a message for debugging any error'),*/
               ]);
       }

       if ( ! Radcheck::where('username', $request->username)->where('password', bcrypt($request->password))->where('flag','=','not active')->first() ) {
           return redirect()->back()
               ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
               ->withErrors([
                   'active' => Lang::get('auth.active'),
               ]);
       }


   }





   protected function credentials(Request $request)
   {
       /*return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');*/
       $crendentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
       $crendentials['flag']='active';
       return $crendentials;
   }
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }

    public function check(){
  $agent = new Agent();
    $dt = Carbon::now();

    $device_name = '';
    if ($agent->isDesktop()) {
        $device_name = 'desktop';
    } elseif ($agent->isTablet()) {
        $device_name = 'tablet';
    } elseif ($agent->isMobile()) {
        $device_name = 'mobile';
    }

    DB::table('device')->insert([
        ['device_name' => $device_name, 'tgl' => $dt->toDateString()],
    ]);

}

}
```

Comment: You know what, just before your `if() else`, try to insert one row and see if it can insert a row. Just do `DB::table('device')->insert(['device_name' => 'desktop', 'tgl' => Carbon::now()->toDateString()]);` If this works, at least we know the issue is not coming from the DB insertion.

Comment: @EddyTheDove, SOLVED... I false in typing enum value in table.... THank you very much for your appreciation And your answer